# ReactiveMongo Play module: Gridfs files serving

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, gridfs, reactivemongo

What is the most canonical way to write serve files with ReactiveMongo  version 0.11.2 on play framework ? In old version I can do it with the following controller function

```
  def img(id: String) = Action.async {
    val file = gridFS.find(BSONDocument("_id" -> BSONObjectID(id)))
    serve(gridFS, file,dispositionMode = "inline")
  }
```

Current MongoController GridFS uses Json serializer/deserializer that does not work direct for me. I am trying to write something like this ...

```
class Admin @Inject() (val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi) extends Controller with MongoController with ReactiveMongoComponents {
...
  def img(id: String) = Action.async {
       val file = reactiveMongoApi.gridFS.find(Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj( "$oid" -> id) 
       serve(reactiveMongoApi.gridFS, file)
  }

}
```

But it does not compiles of course with error on `gridFS.find` line.

```
No Json deserializer found for type T. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.
```

If I'll start to write (actually move from ReactiveMongo) all implicits for deserialisation and serialisation to ReadFile it works - but is there exists some more elegant way for this?

Comment: Please have a look at the [sample app](https://github.com/sgodbillon/reactivemongo-demo-app/blob/master/app/controllers/Articles.scala#L92).

Comment: This app uses abit trickies version of gridfs structure. They use self generated _id as string , not ObjectID.

Comment: That not trick but choice.